# How to draw a line / link between two points on a D3 map based on latitude / longitude?

Tags: d3.js, maps

I am attempting to create a map of the 10 major NASA facilities in D3. I have successfully generated the base United States map and appended NASA logos at each one of the center locations based on a .csv with latitude and longitude. However, I cannot figure out any elegant way to draw lines / links / arcs / connections between the points on the map.

In the code below, I have drawn a line between GSFC and KSC (using the 'var = places', 'var = route', and 'svg.append("path")') but it is on an SVG layer, so it is on top of the logos (which looks awful) and does not scale (or go away would be fine, too) when clicking to zoom in on a state. I would like to be able to draw links between the centers based on the latitude and longitude data from the .csv.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
  fill: #aaaaaa;
}

#states .active {
  fill: #ff0000;
  fill-opacity: .5;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #666666;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.stroke {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.fill {
  fill: #fff;
}

.graticule {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.route {
  fill: none;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

</style>
<body>
    <h2>
      <span>NASA Centers</span>
    </h2>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1000,
    height = 600,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var graticule = d3.geo.graticule();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g");

var places = {
    GSFC: [-76.852587, 38.991621],
    KSC: [-80.650813, 28.524963]
    };

var route = {
  type: "LineString",
  coordinates: [
    places.GSFC,
    places.KSC
  ]
};

var point = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "points")
  .selectAll("g")
    .data(d3.entries(places))
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.value) + ")"; });

point.append("text")
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("dx", "1em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

d3.json("us.json", function(error, us) {
    g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      .on("click", clicked);

    g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);

    d3.csv("nasacenters.csv", function(error, data) {
        g.selectAll("image").data([0])
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "nasalogo.png")
            .attr("width", "30")
            .attr("height", "30")
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]-15;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]-15;
            })

        svg.append("path")
          .datum(route)
          .attr("class", "route")
          .attr("d", path)
          .style("opacity", 0.5);

    });

});

function clicked(d) {
  var x, y, k;

  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }

  g.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

  g.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The .csv file is in the following format:

```
code,center,lat,lon
GSFC,Goddard Space Flight Center,38.991621,-76.852587
KSC,Kennedy Space Center,28.524963,-80.650813
JPL,Jet Propulsion Laboratory,34.200463,-118.176008
DFRC,Dryden Flight Research Center,34.613714,-118.076790
GRC,Glenn Research Center,41.415891,-81.861774
MSFC,Marshall Space Flight Center,34.646554,-86.674368
ARC,Ames Research Center,37.409574,-122.064292
LaRC,Langley Research Center,37.092123,-76.376230
JSC,Johnson Space Center,29.551508,-95.092256
SSC,Stennis Space Center,30.363692,-89.600036
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I modified your example slightly based on the problems you described: http://bl.ocks.org/erikhazzard/6201948

It looks like there are three issues:

1. **Paths draw on top of icon**.  To fix this, you can change the order of when you add items to  the group, or add sub groups to your main `g` group, ensuring the order that you add the groups matches the order you want things to appear.
2. **The paths between points doesn't zoom when you zoom the map**.  To fix this, make sure to add everything to the group that you're modifying the clicked() function.  In this case, your `g` group is being zoomed on, so if you add the paths to the `g` group instead of the `svg` directly the paths will zoom as well. In the example provided, text does also not zoom in - that's because it's added directly to the SVG and not the `g` group that is being transformed.
3. **Paths aren't created automatically from the data**. To fix this, you can generate an array containing LineString objects from the data. For example,

   ```
       for(var i=0, len=data.length-1; i<len; i++){
       // (note: loop until length - 1 since we're getting the next
       //  item with i+1)
           links.push({
               type: "LineString",
               coordinates: [
                   [ data[i].lon, data[i].lat ],
                   [ data[i+1].lon, data[i+1].lat ]
               ]
           });
       }
   ```

   Then, do the standard data join pattern and pass in the `links` list to the data. When you pass in `path` as the `d` attribute, it will generate a great arc based on the coordinates for each item:

   ```
   // Standard enter / update 
   var pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll(".arc")
       .data(links);

   //enter
   pathArcs.enter()
       .append("path").attr({
           'class': 'arc'
       }).style({ 
           fill: 'none',
       });

   //update
   pathArcs.attr({
           //d is the points attribute for this path, we'll draw
           //  an arc between the points using the arc function
           d: path
       })
       .style({
           stroke: '#0000ff',
           'stroke-width': '2px'
       })
   ```

In my example ( http://bl.ocks.org/enoex/6201948 ) I added a transition on the great arc paths to illustrate how the path is drawn based on the order of coordinate pairs passed into the links object.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. Thank you! Seriously, cannot thank you enough. Not only did it solve the issue for me, but your comments are extremely informative and will help me learn how to fix these issues in the future.

Comment: Does ... imageGroup.exit().remove() ... not work when included inside of ... function clicked(d) ... ?

Comment: you may need to call exit() on the selection object...e.g.,  

var pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(links);

...
pathArcs.exit().remove();

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to figure out how to select the logos. I don't know how to select the objects instead of the entire imageGroup.

Comment: Ah, to select the images if they're in the imageGroup, you can do imageGroup.selectAll('image');  If you wanted to remove everything, for instance, you could try something like imageGroup.selectAll('image').data([]).exit().remove();

(that would remove all the images, as the data array you're passing in is empty)

Comment: Great example. I haven't actually tried your code you provided at @bl.ocks.org but I suppose if I wanted to draw routes that go from point A to C via point B I'd have to extend the coordinates array with lat/lon values for point B?

Comment: @walfish3d - yep, it would then draw lines from A to B, then B to C