# d3.geo.path() to draw multiple routes on a map

Tags: d3.js

Given an array of aircraft with a waypoints property containing a string of latitudes and longitudes separately by spaces, is this the most efficient approach to drawing the routes on a map in D3. Is there a more D3-esque approach that passes the aircraft array as the data argument and d(waypoints) to a d3.geo.path() generator similar to a d3.svg.line() generator.

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

draw();

function draw(){    
    for (var i = 0; i < aircraft.length; i++){
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(parse(aircraft[i].waypoints))
            .attr("class", "route")
            .attr("d", path);   
    }
}

function parse(waypoints){
    var route;
    var positions = [];
    var points = waypoints.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i = i + 2) {
        positions.push([parseFloat(points[i + 1]), parseFloat(points[i])]);
    }
    route = {
        type: "LineString",
        coordinates: positions
    }
    return route;
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your data (or dummy data in the same structure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest generating the data before hand (like your parse function does) to build an array that you could pass into a selection.

You might find this example helpful: http://bl.ocks.org/erikhazzard/6201948

Essentially, you would build up your array ahead of time (called `links` in this example), and pass it into the .data() call. Then you can enter and append paths, and pass in a path function as the `d` attribute.

```
    var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(projection);
```

...

```
    // Standard enter / update 
    var pathArcs = arcGroup.selectAll(".arc")
        .data(links);

    //enter
    pathArcs.enter()
        .append("path").attr({
            'class': 'arc'
        }).style({ 
            fill: 'none',
        });

    //update
    pathArcs.attr({
            //d is the points attribute for this path, we'll draw
            //  an arc between the points using the arc function
            d: path
        })
        .style({
            stroke: '#0000ff',
            'stroke-width': '2px'
        })
        // Uncomment this line to remove the transition
        .call(lineTransition); 

    //exit
    pathArcs.exit().remove();
```

There's a bit more info too in this question: [How to draw a line / link between two points on a D3 map based on latitude / longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165533/how-to-draw-a-line-link-between-two-points-on-a-d3-map-based-on-latitude-lon/18166108#18166108)

Comment: Heads up there's a 404 on the link http://bl.ocks.org/enoex/6201948